# LiveCycle Designer Form

Tags: designer, livecycle

I've got a LiveCycle Designer Form that I've linked to a SQL Server database, some of the functionalities I'v defineand are working well, however the same can't be said for the insert / update functionality, I've searched up and down the various forums I know and couldn't come up with a solution, can anyone on StackOverflow lend a hand.

Regards

Comment: Please replace the heading "LiveCycle Designer Form" with something more descriptive of the actual problem, e. g. "How to insert/update SQL database from LiveCycle Designer form". Then people going through a list of questions would more likely click and read your question and chances are higher you'll get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you using an ODBC connection? If so, you should consider shifting to a web-service based way to connect to your DB. Would be glad to help, but need to know more about your context